# Query fail with no error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database UTF8 encoded, because it contains arabic letters. I have a php file to select all values from a given table:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        $host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
        $db = "kalimat"; //Your database name
        $user = "root"; //Your database user
        $pass = ""; //Your password
        $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        //Check to see if we can connect to the server
        if(!$connection)
        {
            die("Database server connection failed.");
            die(mysqli_error($db)); 
        }
        else
        {
            //Attempt to select the database
            $dbconnect = mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
            //Check to see if we could select the database
            if(!$dbconnect)
            {
                die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
            }
            else
            {
                $auteur=utf8_decode(urldecode($_GET["artist"]));
                //$auteur=utf8_decode($auteur);

                $resultset = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM $auteur");

                if( $resultset )
                {
                $records = array();
                //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
                while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset))
                {
                    $records[] = $r;    
                }

                $records = array_map(function($r) {
                $r['artist'] = utf8_encode($r['artist']);
                return $r;
                }, $records);

                //Output the data as JSON
                echo json_encode($records);
            }

        else{
            die("Error:".mysqli_error()); //Here is the error
        }
            }
        }
?>
```

In output, I have "`Error:`" without any specification, so I can't know the source of the problem.
Any something strange in the php file?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ferozakbar: same problem, no error printed.

Comment: Try temporarily deleting or commenting `else{die("Error:".mysql_error()); //Here is the error}` and see if it echos anything.

Comment: @androniennn ,there might be problem in your select db ..I have mentioned in answer.Did you check.Probably that might be error,even I encountered same kind of error

Comment: @ilias: I deleted it and nothing is printed.

Comment: what does this if you `echo $auteur ;` ? give what it echo

Comment: bro,try to debug everywhere by putting `or die(mysqli_error())` at selecting db,at query ...

Comment: @echo_Me: Good idea, I already printed it, and it gives me interrogation marks `???`. I then replaced `$auteur` in the query with an UTF8 encoded arabic word (a table name that I have in the db), same problem.

Comment: This question appears to be offtopic because it's on silly typo.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I repeat, I already tried `mysqli_error` and I have the same problem!

Comment: Dude can you show your table name in database ?

Comment: @echo_Me: The table name is `قصي` .

Comment: Never ever have special characters in table names, columns or variables

Comment: I checked `mysqli_error` syntax, and its `mysqli_error($connection)`, and I have `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '???' at line 1` as error

Comment: So i think that @DHS comment is correct, even that we encode/decode the table name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) ?

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;   
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

> utf8mb4 is superset of utf8

**Advice:** database ,table names and columns you should make them in non utf8 characters.

EDIT:

to handle with utf8 characters you have to make all in utf8 such as:

- your files , convert them to utf8 , all pages where you are using utf8 also that page where you geting the author fom.
- database , tables , columns.
- your editor where you write codes.
- headers.
- ...

Comment: I changed the encoding of the database, but I think that the problem is coming from the parameter passed in the query, because it's interpreted as `???`.

Comment: Fortunately that I'm testing yet :) ... So to conclude it's better to do not have special characters in especially table names, table columns and obviously the database name. For the table content, we're free. I tested with a table name that does not contains special characters and it's working without a problem. Thank you very much. Accepted :).

Answer (score -1):

try putting the following lines just after the  php tag starts and error will be displayed.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You are using **mysqli**, not mysql. So you have to use **appropriate error function**, and call it according to it's proper syntax.

Also, your idea on storing data in user-defined tables is wrong. You have to learn relational database basics first.

Comment: If you know there is a wrong and right way of doing it, why not writing the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @DHS because this question is a shame.

Comment: Then make a comment and not an answer